# What will be the output datatype of calculating difference in hours between two dates?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know the `datatype` of below code.... `number` or `date`?

`select round(24*(sysdate - to_date('18-09-18 06:30','YYYY-MM-DD HH24 Mi'))) as Hours_Diff 
from Dual;`

Answer (score 2):

**[TL;DR]** Subtracting one `DATE` from another gives the number of days difference as a number. Multiplying by 24 and rounding it does not change the data type.

*(and subtracting one `TIMESTAMP` from another give the difference as a `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type)*

Longer answer:

```
SELECT DUMP(  round(24*(sysdate - to_date('18-09-18 06:30','YYYY-MM-DD HH24 Mi'))) )
FROM   DUAL
```

*(Note: `to_date('18-09-18 06:30','YYYY-MM-DD HH24 Mi')` will give a year of `0018` not `2018`!)*

Outputs:

```
Typ=2, Len=5: 196, 18, 53, 30, 33
```

[`Typ=2` signifies a number](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41085/sqlqr06002.htm#SQLQR959).